# Insert element using github.com/mikefarah/yq command in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, yq

I have below content in yml file:

```
category:
  toolSettings: settings.xml
```

Below snippet needs to be added to the existing under  category:

```
 env:                
    variables:
       - user: ABC
       - passowrd: BCD
```

Expected Output:

```
category:
  env:                
    variables:
       - user: ABC
       - passowrd: BCD
  toolSettings: settings.xml
```

Tried below:

```
yq e '."category" +=({env: {variables:[ {"user":"ABC"},{"passowrd":"BCD"}]}})'  jules.yml > tmp.yml
```

```
yq -i '.category.env.variables[0].user="ABC"' jules.yml > tmp.yml
yq -i '.category.env.variables[1].passowrd="BCD"' jules.yml > tmp.yml
```

But none of the above are not working .

```
github.com/mikefarah/yq, 
yq Version: 4.26.1
```

Comment: Which program named `yq` is this? There are two completely different programs both called by the same name; their syntax is not mutually compatible. It looks to me like your command is written for the one that uses jq syntax; if you're actually using the one with its own distinct syntax, that would explain things.

Comment: I am trying to use normal yq command that is used for yml file modification

Comment: They're _both_ for YAML modification, and I don't see why one would be more "normal" than the other.

Comment: So -- is this question about https://github.com/mikefarah/yq, or is it about https://github.com/kislyuk/yq?

Comment: (it might also disambiguate if instead of saying "not working" you specified a particular error message; that way the error can be matched against a particular implementation).

Comment: It  is github.com/mikefarah/yq,

Comment: You have to quote `env` and `variables`. I'm not sure what you're trying with your last two commands, as they combine in-place and redirection, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: A note for anyone trying to reproduce this on https://repl.it/ -- if you just install `yq` you get the kislyuk version; for the mikefarah version you need to install `yq-go`.

Comment: Anyhow -- looks to me like if you take out the `>tmp.yml` and let your latter commands just modify `jules.yml` in place, it works fine.

Comment: see above demonstrated at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/EnragedPreviousScans#runme.bash

Comment: hi Charies, if I take out the  >tmp.yml, it just prints the out put in console and not modify the actual file

Comment: That's what it _would_ do if you didn't have `-i`, which tells it to overwrite the input file instead of printing to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

One should use *either* `yq -i` *or* a redirection on stdout, not both together.

---

The following code:

```bash
# Create original file
cat >jules.yml <<'EOF'
category:
  toolSettings: settings.xml
EOF

# Edit that file in-place
yq -i '
  .category.env.variables.user = "ABC"
| .category.env.variables.password = "DEF"
' jules.yml

# Write file to output
echo "New jules.yml file follows:"
echo "---"
cat jules.yml
```

...leaves `jules.yml` with the content:

```yaml
category:
  toolSettings: settings.xml
  env:
    variables:
      user: ABC
      password: DEF
```

...as you can see at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/EnragedPreviousScans#runme.bash

Comment: It is giing error category.env.variables.password  is not recognized as an internal or external command ,operable program or batch file

Comment: That's an error you would get if you were running this with cmd.exe instead of with bash. The question is tagged bash, so I answered for bash, and you need to use bash to run it.